# Passing Two Objects in Rest Api using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I have written a Restful web service API, which is accepting two different Object, Is it possible to call this api using Jersey client. I am not able to call this using Jersey client. **Is this a limitation of Rest API that we can not pass multiple objects to a method.**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class TimePassService {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveEmployeeInfo(final Employee input,final Manager input1) {
        String result = "Employee saved : " + input;

        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println(input1);
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

When I discussed this with some techies, they replied that it is not possible, The solution is to wrap these two object into a third object and then pass a single Object.

Please let me know if there is some other solution of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible. See [the JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> 3.3.2.1 Entity Parameters
>
> The value of a parameter not annotated with `@FormParam` or any of the annotations listed in in Section 3.2, called the entity parameter, is mapped from the request entity body. Conversion between an entity body and a Java type is the responsibility of an entity provider, see Section 4.2. Resource methods MUST have at most one entity parameter.

There can be only *one* method 'entity parameter'.

What you ask for would not be RESTful. REST ist not RPC (Remote Procedure Call), you don't 'pass' objects to a 'method'. In REST you transfer Resource representations from and to identifying URLs.

In your example the Resource would be an `EmployeeInfo` wrapping `Employee` and `Manager`.

Besides, `/post` is not a very RESTful URL. What Resource is identified by this? What happens if you `GET /post`? Please think in REST terms, not in RPC.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to wrap these two object into a third object and then pass a single Object.
I wonder string json that post from client how does it look like?

is it this :

```
[
    employee: {
        "name": "Sury",
        "age": 23
    },
    manager: {
        "name": "Beack",
        "Room": "DC2"
    }
]
```