# Is it good to use FormParam jersey with angular Js?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey-2.0

I've used angular js as front end technology and jersey to create web services in JAVA. My certain forms have fields that belongs to different beans. I know it is not good practice to have two resources in single POST request. Another option left is to use `@FormParam` annotation that requires lots of manual work to cast form fields to java objects. I've gone through both questions below.

[JAX-RS Post multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553218/jax-rs-post-multiple-objects)

[Passing Two Objects in Rest Api using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161403/passing-two-objects-in-rest-api-using-jersey)

Comment: Just combine them into a single JSON object. Why do they need to be separate?

Comment: They both are different entities having parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

i think ajax is better for you, you can send both POST and GET in the same time
first put the ajax code in jquery function after that get the function on element change or click
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry, it will not be helpful in this case.